# how to change a pandas values if the timeframe of that row if on another pandas

Tags: python, pandas

im doing some DataFrame manipulation over pandas, i made this two tables, here is a little part of the first

```
df2 this has a type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

    timestamp   open    high    low     close   time    equity  balance     position
datetime                                    
2021-10-27 00:40:00     1635313200000   4268.13     4285.00     3890.17     3995.06     1635292800000000000     1000.0  1000.0  0
2021-10-28 00:00:00     1635397200000   3995.06     4405.50     3981.23     4355.00     1635379200000000000     1000.0  1000.0  0
2021-10-29 00:00:00     1635483600000   4355.01     4460.47     4278.70     4336.78     1635465600000000000     1000.0  1000.0  0
2021-10-30 00:00:00     1635570000000   4336.77     4399.14     4232.20     4367.59     1635552000000000000     1000.0  1000.0  0
2021-10-31 00:00:00     1635656400000   4367.58     4374.89     4146.30     4225.00     1635638400000000000     1000.0  1000.0  0
2021-11-01 00:00:00     1635746400000   4225.00     4386.58     4198.55     4365.10     1635724800000000000     1000.0  1000.0  0
2021-11-02 00:00:00     1635832800000   4365.09     4639.98     4330.02     4559.36     1635811200000000000     1000.0  1000.0  0
2021-11-03 00:00:00     1635919200000   4559.36     4665.87     4455.00     4539.73     1635897600000000000     1000.0  1000.0  0
```

also i got from a algoritmig trading strategy, a dataframe representing the singals here it is
signals

```
datetime
2021-11-28 00:00:33.726288     1
2021-12-06 13:00:14.885480     1
2021-12-06 13:00:16.520445    -1
2021-11-28 00:00:42.704140    -1
2021-12-10 04:00:15.557555     1
2021-12-10 04:00:15.611935     1
2021-12-10 06:00:17.704981    -1
2021-12-10 06:00:18.404945    -1
Name: position, dtype: object
```

this has a type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

now i am trying to change the position value on the first dataframe to 1 or -1(acording to the position column in the signals dataframe for the rows that has the datetime equal to the second dataframe, i know that it may be posible that the extact datetime can not be on the column, so i tried to make stuff like

```
df2['position']= signals_orders[df2['position'][signals_orders.index==df2.index]]
```

but as i suspect there is an length error, i hope you can helpme thanks in advance

edition:

i used the code from mozway

```
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
signals_orders.index = pd.to_datetime(signals_orders.index)
df2 = df2.sort_index()

# merge
out = (pd
       .merge_asof(df2.drop(columns='position'),
            signals_orders.sort_index(), 
            left_index=True, right_index=True, )
       .assign(position=lambda d: d['position'].fillna(df2['position']))
       )
```

but now the position column is giving a lot of -1 that should not be there

```
2021-10-27 00:40:00     1635313200000   4268.13     4272.00     4264.41     4272.00     2021-10-27 00:40:00     0
2021-10-27 00:45:00     1635313500000   4271.99     4277.40     4263.17     4277.39     2021-10-27 00:45:00     0
2021-10-27 00:50:00     1635313800000   4277.40     4277.92     4266.12     4270.95     2021-10-27 00:50:00     0
2021-10-27 00:55:00     1635314100000   4270.94     4280.00     4269.67     4273.46     2021-10-27 00:55:00     0
2021-10-27 01:00:00     1635314400000   4273.46     4285.00     4272.15     4273.11     2021-10-27 01:00:00     0
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2021-12-11 06:40:00     1639226400000   4037.62     4048.55     4037.34     4048.55     2021-12-11 06:40:00     -1
2021-12-11 06:45:00     1639226700000   4048.55     4049.00     4035.14     4035.31     2021-12-11 06:45:00     -1
2021-12-11 06:50:00     1639227000000   4035.32     4042.38     4035.31     4037.37     2021-12-11 06:50:00     -1
2021-12-11 06:55:00     1639227300000   4037.37     4042.44     4030.90     4038.15     2021-12-11 06:55:00     -1
2021-12-11 07:00:00     1639227600000   4038.14     4043.81     4024.55     4025.42     2021-12-11 07:00:00     -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should join the make your series into a dataframe with

```
signals_frame = signals_orders.to_frame()
```

Then you should join to df2 dataframe on the index

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df2, signals_frame)
```

And then you should update the values in the resultant dataframe.

```
merged_df['position'] = merged_df['whatever_the_column_for_your_1_or_negative_1_is']
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i tried but  im getting an empty dataset, also the colum is named position in both dataframes, should i change one?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you should use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
# ensure datetime
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
signals_orders.index = pd.to_datetime(signals_orders.index)

# merge
out = (pd
       .merge_asof(df2.drop(columns='position'),
            signals_orders.sort_index(), 
            left_index=True, right_index=True, )
       .assign(position=lambda d: d['position'].fillna(df2['position']))
       )
```

Output:

```
                         timestamp     open     high      low    close                 time  equity  balance  position
datetime                                                                                                              
2021-10-27 00:40:00  1635313200000  4268.13  4285.00  3890.17  3995.06  1635292800000000000  1000.0   1000.0       0.0
2021-10-28 00:00:00  1635397200000  3995.06  4405.50  3981.23  4355.00  1635379200000000000  1000.0   1000.0       0.0
2021-10-29 00:00:00  1635483600000  4355.01  4460.47  4278.70  4336.78  1635465600000000000  1000.0   1000.0       1.0
2021-10-30 00:00:00  1635570000000  4336.77  4399.14  4232.20  4367.59  1635552000000000000  1000.0   1000.0       1.0
2021-10-31 00:00:00  1635656400000  4367.58  4374.89  4146.30  4225.00  1635638400000000000  1000.0   1000.0       1.0
2021-11-01 00:00:00  1635746400000  4225.00  4386.58  4198.55  4365.10  1635724800000000000  1000.0   1000.0       1.0
2021-11-02 00:00:00  1635832800000  4365.09  4639.98  4330.02  4559.36  1635811200000000000  1000.0   1000.0      -1.0
2021-11-03 00:00:00  1635919200000  4559.36  4665.87  4455.00  4539.73  1635897600000000000  1000.0   1000.0      -1.0
```

*NB. I used a modified input for signals_orders:*

```
datetime
2021-10-28 00:00:33.726288    1
2021-11-01 13:00:14.885480   -1
2021-12-06 13:00:16.520445   -1
```

Comment: thanks man! i tried but i get this error ValueError: left keys must be sorted what can it be?

Comment: The keys must be sorted for a `merge_asof` add `.sort_index()`: `...merge_asof(df2.sort_index().drop...`

Comment: thanks i add it behind and now is runing but i see some strange behavior, im updating the question

Comment: @mimus do you want to change position only on the first match? If yes you need to change the order of the merge. I can't update now but give it a try and let me know if you don't manage

Comment: yes indeed sorry if i was not clear, i want to change the position for the row that hits on that date, i am adding buy/sell signals to a trading bot backtester so i need to have the position on 1/-1/0 but the positions signals came from another function, let me try as you say, thanks!

Comment: no man, sorry i tried to change the order of the left and right dataframes but i get ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels